# Inserting text into input in descendant component with React

Tags: reactjs

I'm diving into react for the first time but I'm having some difficulty with a particular requirement.  I have the following component structure:

Survey
--QuickTextOptions
----QuickTextOption
--Question
----Answer
------TextAnswer

As you probably can tell, I'm working on a survey application.  A survey author would create a question, then answers (i.e. sub questions or options).  There will be a number of different answer types including checkbox and text.

Also at the top of the survey, above the questions, are a list of "quick text" options.  When one of these is selected, some text is appended to the value field of the appropriate TextAnswer's input field.  A user can select as many of these as they'd like.

This is trivial to do with just javascript, but I can't figure out a good way to do this with React without adding refs to components down the chain of the survey.

If I pass it in as a prop, have AnswerText as a controlled component, and set value={this.state.value + this.props.quickText}. It just re-inserts the text on the handleChange event of AnswerText.

I'm considering using refs and calling child functions from parents but refs seem to be discouraged and I'll have to do this for Question, Answer, and AnswerText in order to pass it down the chain which seems a bit too much.

Is there any other way to fire an event to a descendant down the chain with some data?  It's a one time addition so props seem to not work well for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you use something like **FLUX** and global state? In my practice, usually you build such app working around global state which stores your input data. This way you can edit it transparently from different places according to action events (the only ones which can modify that input value, inputs themselves are not doing that).

So I see that it should look like this:

1. You pass references to global state object deep into your components and to your form's input.
2. When you start typing each new character triggers event to modify global state value for this input. You're getting updated value instantly in your  component's props and component renders newly entered character.
3. When you want to modify input from some other component (by pressing button) you do almost the same. You click on button and it triggers event saying that global state value for that input should have "some string" added. Your input component receives callback with new props and renders this text instantly.

By saying event I mean special event which gets some value and inserts it into global state. Rest is done by framework.

Hope this will help you to design your app. The approach I described above is a short description of how [Tictail Talk](https://tictail.com/talk/) web chat client works now.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.  I've been thinking about using Redux but deferred that until I got a hang of React but it looks like I'm gonna have to jump into it sooner than I expected.

Thanks again!